# Extracting the numbers from a pandas dataframe column with string objects using regex and .apply

Tags: python, regex, pandas, function, lambda

I have a pandas dataframe column with string features:

[feature details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ux8Y.png)

I wrote a function using regex to extract the number and store it as an integer in a new column. It appears to work on a slice of columns, but not on the entire dataframe. I tried making some adjustments based on similar posts but no luck. Though it doesn't return an error, it simply doesn't return anything and gets stuck processing the cell, and using my entire CPU power. Could it be just that my computer isn't powerful enough?

The data frame is over 350,000 rows.

Below is a sample of the code to show the function and testing on two rows, as well as the two ways I tried applying to the entire dataframe commented out. Thank you in advanced for any help!

[code sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j2l5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Just stuck computing for hours. Even left it overnight and found it in the same condition the next morning.

It is really strange that this takes your computer that long - here on an `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v4 @ 3.20GHz` your `df.emp_length.apply(lengthStrip)` for 350,000 rows is done in less than a second. Anyway, the execution time could be reduced by applying already compiled functions rather than the user-defined `lengthStrip`:

```
import ctypes
import ctypes.util
libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(ctypes.util.find_library('c'))
df['emp_length'] = df.emp_length.apply(lambda y: libc.atoi(y.encode()))
```

Comment: I agree it's really strange and it makes me think there is something wrong with the code or perhaps the way I'm understanding the feature. As you can see in the function I wrote, I had to add that first if statement because the regex.findall would only work as intended on the rows that begin with a number instead of that "<".

Comment: For the timebeing I tried our suggestion with an error output: AttributeError: module 'ctypes' has no attribute 'util'

Comment: Sorry, I notice that my suggestion wasn't correct, it hopefully is now, but the speed win is reduced. Still, I also tried your function as I said, and it wasn't that slow here.

Comment: That worked! I appreciate the help here, though I'll still be looking into why my function either wasn't working or was taking forever. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `df['empLength'] = df['empLength'].apply(lengthStrip)`.

It should apply the function you wrote on each value in the column and replace the contents of that column with the new values.

Comment: My apologies, I have also tried it that way with the same result. Just stuck computing for hours. Even left it overnight and found it in the same condition the next morning.